# Height of <ul> with absolute positioning (in a Responsive Design)

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a slideshow, of sorts, which is triggered using jQuery and cycles through images in a ul. The images are styled with CSS to be absolutely positioned as to overlap and they casually fadeIn and fadeOut.

**The Problem**

I gave each image a max-width of 100% as part of my responsive design and the ul a static height, but of course the images change height depending on screen-size.

**Solution**

It is possible to check with jQuery the size of the images once they've loaded and size the ul accordingly - but this leads to a nasty flicker as the images are loaded.

Is there a CSS solution?

Much is explained through this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eddturtle/vvsDh/1/

Comment: Do you need the absolute positioning on the `LI`'s?

Comment: They allow me to overlay the images on top of each other...

Comment: Why do you need to set the height of the ul?

Comment: Don't have the exact solution, but maybe that link could help you built your responsive carousel : http://filamentgroup.com/lab/responsive_carousel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to come up with something by instead using background images as CSS3 has a 'background-size' property that you can set to 'cover'. [Here's the doc](http://w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp).

What I might do is hide your list of images and instead create an image holder for each transition and set it's CSS background property. Have this new holder fade in, and use the callback for the fadeIn function to remove the previous holder from the DOM. I could maybe edit the fiddle for you and get this solution running if you need me to.

EDIT***

Here ya go dude. This should work exactly as you need it to. As it is right now the background image is set to cover, which will make sure the image fills the entire area. If you want to make sure the entire image is displayed and ratio constrained, use contain. All you need to do is adjust the parent #slideshow height to what you need it to be.

http://jsfiddle.net/vvsDh/5/

Comment: This is the only way I see it being done with an elegant CSS solution. This saves you the hassle by using CSS3's built in image sizing instead of having to roll your own in javavscript.

Comment: I don't understand how you could keep the image proportions when the width changes. How would you define the height of the div?

Comment: this is as far as I could get with the background-size idea: http://jsfiddle.net/eddturtle/wpA8F/3/ Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Well your going to either need a static height or set whatever the parent div is to 100%. If you use static heights, you can use CSS3 media queries to adjust the height as your screen size gets smaller. That's really your only two options.

Comment: I need to break for dinner, but this is working other than the backslashes not coming through in the url. Need to do some string manipulation and URL encode them I'm thinking. I'll update the answer with the fiddle when its done.

Comment: PS just simply resize the Fiddle to get an idea of what it does.